# SVN: Revert commit while preserving local changes

Tags: svn, local, revert

So I have a local build file.

It shouldn't be in SVN at all, but, it is. (Thanks, previous maintainer!) But changes have been made to the local copy, which only apply to building on the box it's on.

I screw up and do a commit that commits this local build file. Now the SVN repo copy has these local changes; this is bad.

How can I get back to *status quo ante*, where the local changes are in the local copy, not in the SVN repo, *and* a subsequent `svn update` won't overwrite the local changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. backup the file with the local changes somewhere.
2. do a show log on the file, and revert this file to the revision before the unwanted changes (using an update with the given revision number)
3. commit the file
4. update the whole working copy
5. restore the backup done at step 1

You might use changelists or lock the file to avoid making the same mistake again.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But seriously, there's not an easier way baked into SVN? I *can't* have been the first person (idiot) to do this.

Comment: I don't really see how it might be easier. You need to keep the local changes, so a backup is necessary. You need to revert to a previous revision so you have to tell which. SVN can't guess it for you. Usually, if some file shouldn't be committed, it shouldn't be in SVN.

Comment: > Usually, if some file shouldn't be committed, it shouldn't be in SVN. True dat. ;(

Comment: There has to be a way to do this with svn commands, without the need to copy files to a different place...

Comment: @MihaiAlexandruBîrsan: good luck finding one. If you're the downvoter, could you suggest an alternative?

Comment: I could not commit the file in step 3.  "svn stat" on the file doesn't show it's been modified even though inspecting the file shows that it has been reverted to the previous revision.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can not store in WC "local only" changes, if changed files are versioned (except adding set to ignore-list)
2. You can undo any previous commit(s) by reverse-merging

Answer (score 0):

For me this one works:

```
> svn st
M       0027
> svn info 0027 | grep URL
URL: svn://localhost/xxx/trunk/0027
> svn rm -m "remove accidently checked in file" svn://localhost/xxx/trunk/0027
Revision ...
> svn update
   C 0027
At revision 42.
Summary of conflicts:
  Tree conflicts: 1
> svn revert 0027
Reverted '0027'
> svn status
?       0027
```

So file `0027` is still alive, has it's old contents but is not in the repo anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If your file shouldn't be versioned, you can un-version it:

```
svn rm --keep-local filename
```

This will keep any local file, but SVN will stop tracking it.